# How to explain these multiprocessing execution results?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I met such a problem: it has some mutually independent big tasks, and each task has some following mutually independent small tasks that depend on the result of the big task. I did some experiments on Python 3.10.4 to find how can I utilize laziness to fill the multiprocessing pool. The code is as follows:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import chain


def measure(f):
    start = time.time()
    f()
    print(f'{f.__name__}: {time.time() - start}')


def big_task(_):
    time.sleep(3)
    return range(3)


def small_task(_):
    time.sleep(1)


p = Pool(4)


# total: 11s
@measure
def test1():
    for i in p.map(big_task, range(5)):
        p.map(small_task, i)


# total: 8s
@measure
def test2():
    for i in p.imap(big_task, range(5)):
        p.map(small_task, i)


# total: 10s
@measure
def test3():
    p.map(
        small_task,
        chain.from_iterable(
            p.imap(big_task, range(5))
        )
    )


# total: 8s
@measure
def test4():
    list(p.imap(
        small_task,
        chain.from_iterable(
            p.imap(big_task, range(5))
        )
    ))
```

I know how to explain the result of `test1`. It takes 6s to finish the outer loop and 10 * 1s to finish the inner loop. But I don't know how to explain the results of other tests because I can't figure out how `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` works internally and how lazy the iterable argument in `map`/`imap` is (i.e., when will the `next(iter)` be called).

I also did another experiment that changes `Pool(4)` to `Pool(8)` and changes `range(5)` to `range(10)`. The results were 16s, 13s, 10s, 8s, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I try to add logging and see how the tasks are distributed. Here is the code:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process, Value, Array
from itertools import chain

worker_num = 4
big_task_num = 5

start = Value('d', 0.0)
table = [Array('c', b' ' * 40) for _ in range(worker_num)]


def measure(f):
    start.value = time.time()
    for r in table:
        r.value = b'| ' * 20
    f()
    print(f'##### {f.__name__}: {time.time() - start.value}s #####')
    print('\n'.join(r.value.decode() for r in table))
    print(flush=True)


def write_table(msg):
    proc_idx = int(current_process().name[len('ForkPoolWorker-'):]) - 1
    time_idx = int(time.time() - start.value) * 2 + 1
    table[proc_idx][time_idx:time_idx + len(msg)] = msg


def big_task(_):
    write_table(b'b b b')
    time.sleep(3)
    return range(3)


def small_task(_):
    write_table(b's')
    time.sleep(1)


p = Pool(worker_num)


@measure
def test1():
    for i in p.map(big_task, range(big_task_num)):
        p.map(small_task, i)


@measure
def test2():
    for i in p.imap(big_task, range(big_task_num)):
        p.map(small_task, i)


@measure
def test3():
    p.map(
        small_task,
        chain.from_iterable(
            p.imap(big_task, range(big_task_num))
        )
    )


@measure
def test4():
    list(p.imap(
        small_task,
        chain.from_iterable(
            p.imap(big_task, range(big_task_num))
        )
    ))
```

Here is the result for `worker_num = 4` and `big_task_num = 5`:

```
##### test1: 11.0163254737854s #####
|b b b| | | |s|s|s| |s| | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s| |s|s|s| | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s| |s|s| | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b| |s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 

##### test2: 8.008505821228027s #####
|b b b|s|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s| |s| | | | | | | | | | | | 

##### test3: 10.010857343673706s #####
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 

##### test4: 8.006532430648804s #####
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Here is the result for `worker_num = 8` and `big_task_num = 10`:

```
##### test1: 16.0493221282959s #####
|b b b| | | |s| |s| | |s| | |s| | | | | 
|b b b| | | | |s| | |s| |s| | |s| | | | 
|b b b| | | |s| | |s| |s| | |s| | | | | 
|b b b| | | | |s| | |s| | |s| | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b| | |s| | |s| |s| | | | | | 
|b b b| | | | |s| |s| | |s| | |s| | | | 
|b b b| | | |s| | |s| | |s| |s| | | | | 
|b b b|b b b| | |s| |s| | |s| |s| | | | 

##### test2: 13.053321838378906s #####
|b b b| |s| |s| |s| | |s| | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b| |s| | |s| |s| | | | | | | 
|b b b| |s| |s| | |s| |s| | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s| |s| |s| | |s| | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s| |s| | |s| |s| | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s| |s| | |s| | |s| | | | | | | | 
|b b b| |s| |s| | |s| | |s| | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b| |s| |s| | |s| | | | | | | 

##### test3: 10.020010232925415s #####
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b| | | |s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | 

##### test4: 8.007385969161987s #####
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|b b b|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | | 
|b b b|s|s|s|s|s| | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Some observations:

- `map` will immediately turn `iterable` into `list(iterable)`, then apply them to each task.
- `imap` will call `next` on `iterable` lazily.
- Once `imap` is called, it starts executing on the background. If we call `next` on the iterator, we will block until the result is returned. It does not postpone the execution of tasks to the time we call `next` on it.